# Does lastIndexOf in Java search from end of String?

Tags: java, string, performance

I've been googling around and trying to find out what is the behaviour of lastIndexOf, but can't really find the answer to it...

I have a potentially large string that I need to search, and I'm 99% positive that a tag, ex: `</data>` will be at the end of it. I am trying to strip that off and append some extra data to the string and then close it off again after.

Right now I'm using indexOf, but performance is my top priority here, so I was thinking of using lastIndexOf...

Could some expert with Java confirm whether lastIndexOf would search from the back of the string?

Example:

```
xml = xml.substring(0, xml.lastIndexOf("</data>"));
xml+"<mystuff>hello world</mysruff>";
xml+"</data>";
```

Comment: You know the source is available, right?

Comment: Why are you using string operations to work with XML? Use an XML API. Oh, and if performance is your top priority you shouldn't be performing multiple string concatenations like that...

Comment: @DaveNewton no, I had no idea until now. sorry for the newbie question... :(

Comment: @codenamezero No reason to apologize, just pointing it out.

Comment: All - why the downvotes?  Because he didn't know the source was available or where to get the documentation?  Isn't that what SO is for - couldn't you have just said, "I see based on your question that you're missing this piece of critical information that would be useful to you - here's how you can find your answer"...?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28java.lang.String,%20int%29):

> int lastIndexOf(String str, int fromIndex) 
>             Returns the index within this string of the last occurrence of the specified substring, searching backward starting at the specified index.

Answer (score 5):

Based on [the source found here](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Core/lang/java/lang/String.java.htm), it appears as if `lastIndexOf` does traverse from the end of the string, towards the beginning.  An excerpt is posted below for convenience; note the decrement operations as it is keeping track of `i` and `j` to find the last match.

```
startSearchForLastChar: while (true) {
    while (i >= min && source[i] != strLastChar) {
        i--;
    }
    if (i < min) {
        return -1;
    }
    int j = i - 1;
    int start = j - (targetCount - 1);
    int k = strLastIndex - 1;

    while (j > start) {
        if (source[j--] != target[k--]) {
            i--;
            continue startSearchForLastChar;
        }
    }
    return start - sourceOffset + 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#lastIndexOf%28int%29):

> Returns the index within this string of the last occurrence of the
>   specified character. For values of ch in the range from 0 to 0xFFFF
>   (inclusive), the index (in Unicode code units) returned is the largest
>   value k such that:

```
this.charAt(k) == ch
```

> is true. For other values of ch, it is the largest value k such that:

```
this.codePointAt(k) == ch
```

> is true. In either case, if no such character occurs in this string,
>   then -1 is returned. **The String is searched backwards starting at
>   the last character.**

So yes, it does.